# New column is not getting add in onUpgrade Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

**My code**

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 15) {
                String sql = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table(_id INTEGER UNIQUE, vendor_code TEXT UNIQUE, name TEXT, amount DOUBLE, price DOUBLE, unit TEXT, description TEXT, 'group' INTEGER); " +
                        "INSERT INTO temp_table(_id, name, amount, price, unit, description) " +
                        "SELECT _id, name, amount, price, unit, description FROM products_table; " +
                        "DROP TABLE products_table; " +
                        "CREATE TABLE products_table(_id INTEGER UNIQUE, vendor_code TEXT UNIQUE, name TEXT, amount DOUBLE, price DOUBLE, unit TEXT, description TEXT, 'group' INTEGER); " +
                        "INSERT INTO products_table SELECT _id, vendor_code, name, amount, price, unit, description, 'group' FROM temp_table; " +
                        "DROP TABLE temp_table; "

                database.execSQL(sql);
            }
    }
```

The code is working but it doesn't create errors and doesn't alter the table.
Although in DB Browser for SQLite it works right.
Help me pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `execSQL()` from: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String)

> Multiple statements separated by semicolons are not supported.

You are trying to execute multiple statements separated by semicolons in a single `execSql()` call. 
Split the sql statement in 6 or more if needed parts and execute each with a separate `execSql()` call.